# How to define a list of type [Int]?

Tags: haskell

If we define a list constant like

```
Prelude> let list = [1, 2, 3]
```

it will have the following type:

```
Prelude> :t list
list :: [Integer]
```

How can one define such a constant, literal list of type `[Int]`?

Comment: Just give it a type annotation: `let list = [1, 2, 3] :: [Int]`.

Comment: It *should* have type `Num t => [t]`, not `[Integer]`.

Comment: Managed to find the same solution using ```list :: [Int]```. Thanks all the same, @AlexisKing!

Comment: @chepner Only with `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, which I believe is not turned on by default in older versions of ghci. Actually, I'm not sure it's turned on by default with current haskell platform, haven't used it in a while.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
let lst = [1 :: Int, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it can be done with:

```
list :: [Int]
list = [1, 2, 3]
```